# Code block is required, but the programming language is purely graphical

Tags: bug, specific-question, markdown

> Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code.

There is no code in my post, only text and links.

[image: error]

Here is a link to my question: [Limit Drive Starts with Function Block Diagram](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/175496/limit-drive-starts-with-function-block-diagram?noredirect=1#comment333054_175496)

The following is a copy-paste of the edit I am trying to apply:

> I have a drive (modulating fan) which needs to be interlocked and
>   prevented from starting. The requirement is that:
>
> > The drive is limited to 3 starts per hour with a minimum of 10 minutes between starts.
>
> I am programming using function blocks diagrams. Some information to
>   aid in your understanding of the function block diagram I created:
>
> - Program flow follows the execution numbers on the function blocks.
> - Cyan lines show values of the integer short data type.
> - Black lines show binary values (0/1)
> - References (small rounded rectangles with an alphanumeric identifier and no execution number) are used to *move* data without
>     the need for connecting lines.
>
> Many of the blocks used are self-explanatory, however, the following
>   information may be of use:
>
> - "diss" function block - routes either "in1" or "in2" to "out" depending on "bse". When "bse" equals 0 "in1" is used.
> - "ccob"/"ccos" depends on the "mode". 1=rising edge, 2=falling edge.
> - "dvss" function block - outputs the min/max of the two inputs.
>
> [ I have broken the Function Block Diagram into three views:
>   [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ve6d2.png) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vH57S.png) [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rK3bH.png) ]
>
> Here is the function block diagram, I am interested in alternate or
>   more efficient methods to achieve the requirement. Criticism and help
>   is desired.
>
> I have exported my loop diagram as an SVG: http://svgshare.com/s/306

Comment: Note that your question will be closed as off-topic if it's just text and links. You **must** include the code to be reviewed *in the question body itself*. This particular case is an interesting edge-case though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I copied [the code that you have in this question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/d51b460c-4805-49ee-b2b1-acc628db0a9e/view-source) into the main question. It worked fine, with no problems for me. I can't say what the problem is, as it worked without me changing anything.

---

The only thing that I can think is a problem is it may have thought `[view1]:`, etc., were code, rather than hyperlinks. This is as it is standard to indent them by two spaces. So rather than using:

```
[view1]: url
[view2]: url
[view3]: url
```

Use:

```
  [view1]: url
  [view2]: url
  [view3]: url
```

Other than that, it may have thought that your links `[1][view1]`, etc., were code too. The easiest way to fix this would be to remove the newlines between the links, making them just one line long.

Again this is all idle thought, it may have been neither of these, and some odd bug. But again a verbatim copy and pasted ([from here](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/d51b460c-4805-49ee-b2b1-acc628db0a9e/view-source)) of your Meta question to Main worked fine.

Comment: Yes I can see that you have. Thank you.

Comment: " It worked fine, with no problems for me. " Might reputation difference have something to do with it?

Comment: @Mast No, I get that message when I don't indent code. (Always annoying 'cause I paste then ctrl-k the code.)